# SOLR group by for non blank values

Tags: php, solr

I have some set of products in SOLR, which have been mapped to group_id but for some of the products the group_id is left as blank

But when I want to group by "group_id", it works fine with products which have respective group_id.

But for the one's which have no group_id assigned, i.e. blank are also grouped together. Is there any way I can define to group only group_id which are not blank?

I tried couple of solutions but no luck,

```
&group=true&group.field=config_group&group.main=true
```

and also tried to add a group.query like

```
&group=true&group.field=config_group&group.main=true&group.query=config_group:[1%20TO%20*]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a simple fix to my query

```
&group.query=-config_group:[1%20TO%20*]
```

Which means group only those between 1 to infinity